# Javascript RegExp object working in Chrome, Firefox but not in IE 11 (Syntax error in regular expression)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex test which is looking for dates in the format nn/nnnn and that are 01-12/20nn or 01-12/19nn - i.e. a month followed by a year that makes rough sense.

What I have is this `/^([0-1][0-9][\/]([1][9]|[2][0])[0-9][0-9])$/` which works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but fails with the error `Syntax error in regular expression` on IE 11.

The regex also passes tests on www.regex101.com and performs as expected there.

I have included a full example below - I am a bit stuck because I am certain the regex is absolutely fine.

Any help would be much appreciated - what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>This is the title</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var pattern = new RegExp(/^([0-1][0-9][\/]([1][9]|[2][0])[0-9][0-9])$/, 'i');

        var goodInput = "12/2012";
        var badInput = "1b/g212";

        if(!pattern.test(goodInput))
        {
            console.log("Good Input was NOT OK");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Good Input was OK");
        }

        if(!pattern.test(badInput))
        {
            console.log("Bad Input was NOT OK");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Bad Input was OK");
        }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

    This is the body

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no need for `new RegExp` when you do not have a string. `var pattern = /^([0-1][0-9][\/]([1][9]|[2][0])[0-9][0-9])$/i;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `new RegExp` from an existing regexp. This is an ES6 feature not supported in IE11. See [this blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/regexp-es6.html) for details. Browser compatibility details for this usage can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility). It is described in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp-constructor); note the *patternIsRegexp* case.

Either of the following will work:

```
var pattern = /^([0-1][0-9][\/]([1][9]|[2][0])[0-9][0-9])$/i;
```

or

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^([0-1][0-9][/]([1][9]|[2][0])[0-9][0-9])$", "i");
```

By the way, why are you writing `[1]` instead of `1`? Why are you writing `[\/]` instead of `\/`?